# Is there an easy way to copy an iterator into a list in Java?

Tags: java, list, iterator, copy

I want something like this:

```
public void CopyIteratorIntoList(Iterator<Foo> fooIterator) {
    List<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
    fooList.addAll(fooIterator);
}
```

which should be equivalent to:

```
public void CopyIteratorIntoList(Iterator<Foo> fooIterator) {
    List<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
    while(fooIterator.hasNext())
        fooList.add(fooIterator.next());
}
```

Is there any method in the API to achieve that, or is this the only way?

Comment: I think you would either want 'return fooList' in that method, or pass in the fooList as a parameter, because otherwise that method is actually basically a no-op (except for exhausting the Iterator) :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there's nothing like that in the Standard API.

In Java, it's not idiomatic (and thus rather uncommon) to use `Iterator` as part of an API; they're typically produced and immediately consumed.

Answer (score 7):

No, but the [Google Collections library has a nice way to do that](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#addAll(java.util.Collection,java.util.Iterator)) (if you're going to be using some of it's other function - no reason to add that dependency just for that):

```
Iterators.addAll(targetCollection, sourceIterator);
```

Answer (score 7):

In [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/) (Google's new general-purpose Java library, which supersedes google-collections), this could be simply:

```
return Lists.newArrayList(fooIterator);
```

or if the List will be read-only:

```
return ImmutableList.copyOf(fooIterator);
```

Comment: Or, indeed, Iterators.addAll (as suggested by Carl) if you want to add to an existing collection.

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe that iterators are guaranteed to halt after a fixed number of iterations, so this probably isn't a safe way to insert data into your list. Consider a dummy iterator implementation which always returns the constant `42` from calls to `next()`. Your application will quickly run out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 you can do it like this:

```
public void CopyIteratorIntoList(Iterator<Foo> fooIterator) {
    List<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
    fooIterator.forEachRemaining(fooList::add);
}
```

See also: [Easy way to change Iterable into Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416706/easy-way-to-change-iterable-into-collection)