# Initializing a Set with an Iterable

Tags: java, set, iterable

I want to initialize a Set Implementation (HashSet) in Java with an Iterable. However, the constructor of HashSet doesn't accept Iterables, but only Collections type objects.

Is there a way to convert from Iterable to some subtype of Collections.

Comment: I think the question itself is different enough (since one is an ordered collection) or the other question is not general enough to support both ordered and unordered.

Comment: Well, the linkled duplicate answers the literal question asked by providing "a way to convert from Iterable to some subtype of Collection". However, I agree that this (constructing a temporary `ArrayList`) is not necessarily the best way to intialize a `HashSet` from an `Iterable`.

Comment: If you have Spring Data on the class path you may use `Streamable.of(iterable).toSet()`. If Spring Data happens to be the source of the `Iterable` you have even more options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67413334/66686

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`HashSet` constructor relies on more than what `Iterable` offers: it wants to know the `size` of the collection up front in order to optimally construct the underlying `HashMap`. If you have a true, austere `Iterable`, which doesn't know its size, then you'll have to realize the `Iterable` up front by turning it into a regular `Collection` in any of a number of obvious ways.

If, on the other hand, you have a richer object that already knows its size, then it would pay to create a minimalist adapter class that wraps your `Iterable` into a collection, implementing just `size` in addition to forwarding the call to `iterator`.

```
public class IterableCollection<T> implements Collection<T>
{
   private final Iterable<T> iterable;

   public IterableCollection(Iterable<T> it) { this.iterable = it; }

   @Override public Iterator<T> iterator() { return iterable.iterator(); }

   @Override public int size() { return ... custom code to determine size ... }

   @Override .... all others ... { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
}
```

Comment: Good explanation. I think I get your point and intuition.

Answer (score 56):

You can use [Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#newHashSet-java.lang.Iterable-).

```
Set<T> set = Sets.newHashSet(iterable);
```

or to make it read like a sentence static import,

```
import static com.google.common.collect.Sets.*;

Set<T> set = newHashSet(iterable);
```

Answer (score 6):

Sure, it's shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10117051/201359) answer. Basically, iterate over the iterable and copy its contents in a collection:

```
public static <T> List<T> copyIterable(Iterable<T> iterable) {
    Iterator<T> iter = iterable.iterator();
    List<T> copy = new ArrayList<T>();
    while (iter.hasNext())
        copy.add(iter.next());
    return copy;
}
```

Use it as follows, the resulting `List` object can be passed as a parameter to the `HashSet` constructor.

```
Iterable<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
List<Integer> copy = copyIterable(list);
Set<Integer> aSet = new HashSet<Integer>(copy);
```

**EDIT**

I've been mistaken all along. `Iterable` is a superinterface of `Collection`, so a simple (but unsafe) cast will do the trick, as long as the `Iterable` was a `Collection` to begin with.

```
Iterable<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
Set<Integer> aSet = new HashSet<Integer>((Collection)list); // it works!
```

Comment: I was avoiding to explicitly iterating over Iterable or consuming an Iterator myself. I'm looking for a mechanism so that it is acceptable to the constructor of the HashSet or any Set Implementation. (BTW: I didn't down vote you). But I would definitely upvote you if you can show me a workaround. :-)

Comment: I'm getting this on my Netbeans.

`no suitable constructor found for HashSet(Iterator<Integer>)`

Comment: @WChargin fixed it, thanks. please reconsider the downvote.

Comment: @VaidAbhishek pass the list, not the iterator

Comment: @VaidAbhishek I just realized how simple is the solution to this problem. Please take a look at the update, above

Comment: A `Collection` is an `Iterable`, but an `Iterable` is not necessarily a `Collection`. So, your cast is unsafe (as you stated) and could fail at runtime if the concrete `Iterable` was not also a `Collection`.

Comment: casting an Iterable to a Collection is a bad idea

Comment: @GriffeyDog I was just about to say that. I don't have a list. Infact, I have a custom DT, which exposes Iterator() and Iterable () functionality.

Comment: @GriffeyDog I added a clarification stating this: "as long as the Iterable was a Collection to begin with"

Comment: @VaidAbhishek then, absolutely, you have no option but to copy your custom iterable DT to a proper `Collection`. You should have mentioned this from the beginning!

Answer (score 3):

The [Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface allows the "foreach" syntax to work, so the cleanest way is likely:

```
public <T> Set<T> toSet(Iterable<T> collection) {
    HashSet<T> set = new HashSet<T>();
    for (T item: collection)
        set.add(item);
    return set;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add each one.

```
public static <T> Set<T> setFromIterable(Iterable<T> i) {
    HashSet<T> set = new HashSet<T>();
    Iterator<T> it = i.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        set.add(it.next());
    }
    return set;
}

Iterable<Integer> someIterable = ...;
Set<Integer> someSet = setFromIterable(someIterable);
```

Note that you *don't* use the constructor `new HashSet<Integer>(someIterator)`, because that doesn't exist. Just call the static method.

Comment: I think you are confusing `Iterable` and `Iterator`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But even iterator() doesn't work. The object I have also gives back an Iterator(), but even that is not acceptable to the constructor.

Comment: Kirk: you're right; thanks. @Vaid please see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

I use this one-liner (with Java 8+), which only relies on `java.util.stream`:

```
StreamSupport.stream(myIterable.spliterator(), false).collect(Collectors.toSet());

// or with static imports:
stream(myIterable.spliterator(), false).collect(toSet());
```

Answer (score -3):

Putting somewhat a repeated answer for conciseness. Below worked for me for converting the Iterable of String type to a Set(Java8).

```
Iterable<String> stringIterable = Arrays.asList("str1", "str2", "str3");
Set<String> stringHashSet = new HashSet<>((Collection<? extends String>) stringIterable);
```

Comment: This only works for a `Collection`, and if you already know that you have something more specific then you should type it correctly.