# Parsing JSON array into java.util.List with Gson

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I have a `JsonObject` named `"mapping"` with the following content:

```
{
    "client": "127.0.0.1",
    "servers": [
        "8.8.8.8",
        "8.8.4.4",
        "156.154.70.1",
        "156.154.71.1"
    ]
}
```

I know I can get the array `"servers"` with:

```
mapping.get("servers").getAsJsonArray()
```

And now I want to parse that `JsonArray` into a `java.util.List`...

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easy way to change Iterable into Collection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6416706/978917) or [Convert Iterator to ArrayList](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10117026/978917).

Comment: @ruakh there are many differences between that one and this question. This one deals with `Gson`.

Comment: @AbelMelquiadesCallejo have a look at answer.I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55691694/470749 was helpful for me. `list.add(item.getAsString());`

Answer (score 315, accepted):

Definitely the easiest way to do that is using Gson's default parsing function `fromJson()`.

There is an implementation of this function suitable for when you need to deserialize into any [`ParameterizedType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html) (e.g., any [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)), which is [`fromJson(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT)`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson-com.google.gson.JsonElement-java.lang.reflect.Type-).

In your case, you just need to get the [`Type`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html) of a `List<String>` and then parse the JSON array into that `Type`, like this:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

JsonElement yourJson = mapping.get("servers");
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType();

List<String> yourList = new Gson().fromJson(yourJson, listType);
```

In your case `yourJson` is a [`JsonElement`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html), but it could also be a [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), any [`Reader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) or a [`JsonReader`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html).

You may want to take a look at [Gson API documentation](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md).

Comment: `Type` can be found in what package?

Comment: `Type` is a Java built-in interface located in the package `java.lang.reflect`

Comment: I had to use `getString()` instead of `get()` or else `.fromJson()` was complaining.

Comment: @MikO I have a similar question with Gson [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41029313/how-to-parse-json-into-a-map-using-gson). I wanted to see if you can help me out. I do have a solution but the problem is it looks very messy just to parse a JSON into a Map.

Comment: **Kotlin Extension**

`inline fun <reified T> String.convertToListObject(): List<T>? {
    val listType: Type = object : TypeToken<List<T?>?>() {}.type
    return Gson().fromJson<List<T>>(this, listType)
}`

Answer (score 19):

Below code is using `com.google.gson.JsonArray`.
I have printed the number of element in list as well as the elements in List

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;


public class Test {

    static String str = "{ "+ 
            "\"client\":\"127.0.0.1\"," + 
            "\"servers\":[" + 
            "    \"8.8.8.8\"," + 
            "    \"8.8.4.4\"," + 
            "    \"156.154.70.1\"," + 
            "    \"156.154.71.1\" " + 
            "    ]" + 
            "}";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {

            JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
            JsonObject jo = (JsonObject)jsonParser.parse(str);
            JsonArray jsonArr = jo.getAsJsonArray("servers");
            //jsonArr.
            Gson googleJson = new Gson();
            ArrayList jsonObjList = googleJson.fromJson(jsonArr, ArrayList.class);
            System.out.println("List size is : "+jsonObjList.size());
                    System.out.println("List Elements are  : "+jsonObjList.toString());


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
List size is : 4

List Elements are  : [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4, 156.154.70.1, 156.154.71.1]
```

Answer (score 11):

I read solution from official website of Gson at [here](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#array-examples)

And this code for you:

```
    String json = "{"client":"127.0.0.1","servers":["8.8.8.8","8.8.4.4","156.154.70.1","156.154.71.1"]}";

    JsonObject jsonObject = new Gson().fromJson(json, JsonObject.class);
    JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("servers");

    String[] arrName = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, String[].class);

    List<String> lstName = new ArrayList<>();
    lstName = Arrays.asList(arrName);

    for (String str : lstName) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

Result show on monitor:

```
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
156.154.70.1
156.154.71.1
```

Comment: same answer as the above -- still using the static method `new Gson().fromJson()`

Comment: well my problem was other but your snippet solve my problem. I stored the list of string but  I wanna fetch the strings. Then your snippet recall me of their I can put String[].class to fetch data. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

**Kotlin Extension**

for Kotlin developers you can use this extension

```
inline fun <reified T> String.convertToListObject(): List<T>? {
    val listType: Type = object : TypeToken<List<T?>?>() {}.type
    return Gson().fromJson<List<T>>(this, listType)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the list mapping to work with just using `@SerializedName` for all fields.. no logic around `Type` was necessary.

Running the code - *in step #4 below* - through the debugger, I am able to observe that the `List<ContentImage> mGalleryImages` object populated with the JSON data

Here's an example:

**1. The JSON**

```
   {
    "name": "Some House",
    "gallery": [
      {
        "description": "Nice 300sqft. den.jpg",
        "photo_url": "image/den.jpg"
      },
      {
        "description": "Floor Plan",
        "photo_url": "image/floor_plan.jpg"
      }
    ]
  }
```

---

**2. Java class with the List**

```
public class FocusArea {

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String mName;

    @SerializedName("gallery")
    private List<ContentImage> mGalleryImages;
}
```

---

**3. Java class for the List items**

```
public class ContentImage {

    @SerializedName("description")
    private String mDescription;

    @SerializedName("photo_url")
    private String mPhotoUrl;

    // getters/setters ..
}
```

---

**4. The Java code that processes the JSON**

```
    for (String key : focusAreaKeys) {

        JsonElement sectionElement = sectionsJsonObject.get(key);
        FocusArea focusArea = gson.fromJson(sectionElement, FocusArea.class);
    }
```

Comment: how i access to content image using this way?

Comment: @Adnanhaider, if I understood your question, you want to actually load the image in a viewer?  In the example here, that is what the image url is for.  Here's a thread on how to do so in Android https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776851/load-image-from-url

Comment: i have two class 1. main 2 list shape class.  1 class as parent which attribute is name,id,address, 2 class children, where child name, class name , school name etc. now after set getter setter in model class i get data from json mvvm method and i want to access getter of child class , i only access parent class not child class which give me headache for 2 days still not find answer. so how i access attribute of child class which is already as arraylist .

Comment: @Adnanhaider, I didn't see this message before, justing seeing today.  It sounds like a non-trivial setup.  I would suggest to create a new post and there list minimal code in clean block to demo what you are working with and what you would like it to be doing

Answer (score 0):

Given you start with `mapping.get("servers").getAsJsonArray()`, if you have access to [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) `Streams`, you can do the below one-liner:

```
List<String> servers = Streams.stream(jsonArray.iterator())
                              .map(je -> je.getAsString())
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note `StreamSupport` won't be able to work on `JsonElement` type, so it is insufficient.