# How to use fromGson with arrays

Tags: java, gson

I have the json:

```
{"test": [{"param1": "param"}],
  "test2": "test",
 "test3": "test2"}
```

how can I get fromGson to parse the arrays in a json correctly so that it populates the arrays into an array of a particular object type.

So test should map to `TestObject[] test;`

```
test2 -> String test2;
test3 -> String test3;
```

I tried  `gson.fromJson(response, TestData.class);` that gave me an error: `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 664`

( that the fromJson is not parsing the array in the json correctly).

I also tried going through this post:
[Parsing JSON array into java.util.List with Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544133/parsing-json-array-into-java-util-list-with-gson)

But got confused.

but that did not work

Comment: Please update your feedback when other people have answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

---

Answer

```
public class TestClass {
    public String param1;   
}

public class TestMap {
    public TestClass[] Test;
    public String test2;
    public String test3;
}

public Collection<TestMap> collectionFromJSON(String jsonString) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Collection<TestMap> testMaps = gson.fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<Collection<TestMap>>() {
    }.getType());
    return testMaps;
}

public TestMap singleFromJSON(String jsonString) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Journal testMap = gson.fromJson(jsonString, TestMap.class);
    return testMap;
}
```

Okay, I will explain something here.

---

Explain

Normally if you have a nested array of objects inside another object, you need to create a new class. Ie. if Journal has Categories, Category has two other properties, title and index.

The class will be like

```
class Journal {
    public Category[] categories;
    .... 
}

class Category {
    public String title;
    public Integer index;
    .... 
}
```

So now, the mistake is to confused Array of String and Array of Class. If the json is

```
{"Test", ["Test1", "Test2"...]
 "Test2": "Test3"}
```

You can define it as an array of String. But it is a nested JSON Object, so it has to be class again.

Comment: Sorry, I saw {"test": [{"param1": "param"}], as {"test": ["param1", "param"]. But now it is updated.

Comment: As an aside, don't give answers away so easily, explain it to them and explain what they did wrong.

Comment: Hehe, not too much to explain. It is the way that api is designed for handling the nested array and the experience over a dozen of failure I tried before.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your class, I'm going to guess. This error

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 664

means you are trying to deserialize a `String`, so something like

```
"some string"
```

but what the JSON actually contained was a JSON object, something like

```
{"name" : "value"}
```

Your class is probably mapped wrong. It should be

```
String test2;
String test3;
TestObject[] test;
```

where `TestObject` should be

```
public class TestObject {
    String param1;
}
```

since the JSON contains an JSON string called `param1`.

Comment: should the parameters be listed in any particular order in the java class or just have the same name as the params in the json array?

Comment: @user2491297 The order doesn't matter. Gson will use reflection to retrieve them based on the names found in the JSON and the class you told it to deserialize to.

Answer (score -1):

python has a very useful module called [json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

try `var TestObject=json.parse()`

Comment: Where did you get the idea that python was involved?