# Java webservice json pattern issue

Tags: java, web-services

java webservices returning this value

> {"employee":[{"address":"New Delhi","employeeId":"22222","employeeName":"Abhishek","jobType":"Marketing","salary":"50000"},{"address":"Noida","employeeId":"11111","employeeName":"Dineh Rajput","jobType":"Sr.Software Engineer","salary":"70000"}]}

but I want only

> [{"address":"New Delhi","employeeId":"22222","employeeName":"Abhishek","jobType":"Marketing","salary":"50000"},{"address":"Noida","employeeId":"11111","employeeName":"Dineh Rajput","jobType":"Sr.Software Engineer","salary":"70000"}]

my java webservices main code this:

```
 @GET
     @Path("/json/employees/")
     @Produces("application/json")
     public List<Employee> listEmployeesJSON(){
         return new ArrayList<Employee>(employees.values());
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you are expecting is not valid due to [W3 JSON definition](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp). You can use returned value same as you would use the expected one anyway.

Finally remember that JSON itself is nothing more that string so you can operate on it as on string for example:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class ExpectedJSON{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String string = "{\"employee\":[{\"address\":\"New Delhi\",\"employeeId\":\"22222\",\"employeeName\":\"Abhishek\",\"jobType\":\"Marketing\",\"salary\":\"50000\"},{\"address\":\"Noida\",\"employeeId\":\"11111\",\"employeeName\":\"Dineh Rajput\",\"jobType\":\"Sr.Software Engineer\",\"salary\":\"70000\"}]}";
        String regex = "^[^\\[]+(.+)\\}$";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        matcher.find();
        String group = matcher.group(1);

        System.out.println(group);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you constructing the json object? If you want your json to not contain the employee key, then just remove it from where you are adding it. Both json formats are valid, you can check your json structure [here](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: Cunha how i can remove employee key

Comment: Cunha > am constructing json object like this:

Comment: /* private static Map<String, Employee> employees = new HashMap<String, Employee>();
  private static  List<Employee> list=new ArrayList<Employee>();
     static {
         
         Employee employee1 = new Employee();
         employee1.setEmployeeId("11111");
         employee1.setEmployeeName("Dineh Rajput");
         employee1.setJobType("Sr.Software Engineer");
         employee1.setSalary(70000l);
         employee1.setAddress("Noida");
         list.add(employee1);
         employees.put(employee1.getEmployeeId(),employee1)      
     }

Answer (score 0):

I Wonder why do you need to remove the key of JsonArray Object, if you remove it you lost the reference to the values. By the way,if you think that this way is your solution you can use the [gson](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgson224sourcesjar.htm) library.

You can find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544133/parsing-json-array-into-java-util-list-with-gson).

Hope this help.