# Vert.x Json.decodeValue list

Tags: java, json, list, decode, vert.x

Does anyone know how to decode a json string to `List<Foo>` in vert.x?

You can convert a string to object easily with `Json.decodeValue(data, Foo.class);` but I can't seem to figure out how to do so in case of lists.

So far I've gotten the data out with `Json.decodeValue(data, List.class);` but you can't really do anything with the result apart from print it out.

Comment: I had to use the `Gson.fromJson` API for lists. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544133/parsing-json-array-into-java-util-list-with-gson/18547661#18547661

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to declare a container object, but otherwise, it's quite simple:

```
// This is your Foo
public class MyObj {
    public String key;

    // Just for clarity
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyObj{" +
                "key='" + this.key + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

// This is the container
public class MyArray {
   // Property is mandatory in this case
   @JsonProperty("objs")
   List<MyObj> objs;
}
```

And now the parsing

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {

    // Your input is a JSON array, not a JSON object
    final String input = "[{\"key\":\"a\"}, {\"key\":\"b\"}, {\"key\":\"c\"}]";

    // We format it to be a JSON object, so we can parse it
    final MyArray res = Json.decodeValue(String.format("{\"objs\":%s}", input), MyArray.class);

    // Get your List out
    System.out.println(res.objs);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`List<Foo> fooList = Json.decodeValue(bodyAsString, new TypeReference<List<Foo>>(){});`

TypeReference is Jackson reference for your information

Answer (score -1):

The Json class use Jackson to decode the string.

I recommend you to use a Foo[] instead of a List. If you really need a List, you can easily create one "Arrays.asList(arr)".

Or you can use one of the examples on this site: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-collection-array