# FLAT JSON ARRAY to list of Beans with Jackson JSON lib

Tags: java, json, java-8, jackson

I have a flat json array which look like this :

```
[
  {
    "homeID": "ID1",
    "homeName": "David",
    "childID": "ID1",
    "childName": "AAAA"
  },
  {
    "homeID": "ID1",
    "homeName": "David",
    "childID": "ID2",
    "childName": "AAAAA"
  },
  {
    "homeID": "ID2",
    "homeName": "CASEY",
    "childID": "ID1",
    "childName": "AAAA"
  },
  {
    "homeID": "ID2",
    "homeName": "CASEY",
    "childID": "ID2",
    "childName": "AAAAA"
  }
]
```

Now what i need to do is to decode this JSONARRAY to a List of `list<HOME>` and in this list of HOMES I have a list `list<CHILD>`

my Bean class :

```
public class Home{
    private String homeName;
    private list<CHILD>;

    public Home(){}
}

public class Child{
    private String childName;

    public Child(){}
}
```

So what's the best practice to do this mapping with `Jackson` JSON lib and `java 8` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [**GSON**](https://github.com/google/gson) is what you are looking for, it's a Java API that can read/write from/to JSON in Java, it takes JSON as input and converts it to Java objects.

You will need to write something like:

```
String jsonInString = "{'homeName' : 'home1', 'children': [{'childName': 'child1'}]}";
Home h= gson.fromJson(jsonInString, Home.class);
```

It will give you a `Home` object, you will just edit it to read a `List<Home>`.

It will be something like:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Home>>() {}.getType();
List<Home> yourList = new Gson().fromJson(yourJSONString, listType);
```

This will give you what you are looking for.

You can refer to this [**gson tutorial**](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/) and [**the answer here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18547661/3669624) for further details and reading.

Answer (score 0):

I think [custom deserializers](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomDeserializers) is what you are looking for:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = HomeDeserializer.class)
public class Home {
    private String homeName;
    private List<Child> childs;

    public Home(String homeName, String childName) {
        this.homeName = homeName;
        this.childs = Arrays.asList(new Child(childName));
    }

    // additional constructors
}

public class Child {
    private String childName;

    public Child(String childName) {
        this.childName = childName;
    }

    // additional constructors
}

public class HomeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Home> {

    @Override
    public Home deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        ObjectNode node = p.readValueAsTree();

        JsonNode homeName = node.get("homeName");
        JsonNode childName = node.get("childName");

        return new Home(homeName.asText(), childName.asText());
    }

}
```