# Spring-Data JPA CrudRepository returns Iterable, is it OK to cast this to List?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm writing a code-gen tool to generate backend wiring code for Spring Boot applications using Spring Data JPA and it's mildly annoying me that the methods in the `CrudRepository` return `Iterable` rather than `List`, as `Iterable` doesn't provide quite enough functionality, but `List` does, so I'm looking for the best way to convert the `Iterable` into a `List`.

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416706/easy-way-to-change-iterable-into-collection) on changing an `Iterable` to a `Collection` and I was wondering, rather than using a library like Guava or implementing my own function to do the conversion, why not just cast it to `List`? Is there something wrong with doing that that I don't know about?

**Edit**:
I ask because since it's a code-gen tool it's not reasonable to make it generate code that introduces dependencies on 3rd party libraries, and writing my own function to do the conversion also isn't really reasonable because it would have to live somewhere and I'd rather not have that in the generated code. A simple cast will work, if a little ugly, but just wondered if there's something I'm missing?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

No, I don't think it's OK.

While a `List` is guaranteed to be an `Iterable` an `Iterable` may not be a `List`. This means that if you do cast an `Iterable` to a `List` it may fail at runtime. Even if it works, there's no guarantee that it will continue to work in the future as it could change in new versions of Spring Data JPA without breaking the interface's contract.

Instead of using a cast, you should declare your own query methods that return `List`.

Alternatively you may use `Streamable.of(iterable).toList()` for doing the conversion. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67413334/66686) also contains some background why `Iterable` was chosen as the return type for these methods.

Answer (score 142):

You mentioned `[spring-data-jpa]` so i guess you use JPA. In this case use [`JpaRepository`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html) instead of `CrudRepository` where the methods return `List`'s like you want it.

Comment: Cool. I just took a look at the documentation now. JpaRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository which extends CrudRepository which extends Repository. So it kinda builds on the others. Neat. Yeah, I think the cleanest solution is to switch to JpaRepository.

Comment: this unfortunatelly does not work always. -> for example when you're using a `PagingAndSortingRepository` it is inherited from the `CrudRepository`.

Answer (score 52):

Your interface can still extends the *CrudRepository*, you can just add a new method findAll returning a list. Like example below:

```
@Repository
public interface DataRepository extends CrudRepository<Data, Long> {

    @Override
    List<Data> findAll();

}
```

If you have an "abstract" repository to be extended by all your repositories, you can add this method too, so it will has effect to all your repositories. Like example below:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface GenericRepository<T> extends CrudRepository<T, Long> {

    @Override
    List<T> findAll();

}
```

Comment: Why we don't need to actually implement "List<Data> findAll()"

Comment: Hi Shade.... Spring Data knows how to implement this. We explain what to do using the method declaration and Spring Data do the implementation. Like query methods with filters for example. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods

Comment: @Biga But why when I would like to override `findById` to not return the Optional, I get error `The return type is incompatible with CrudRepository<MyEntity,String>.findById(String)`?

Answer (score 6):

Starting from Spring Data 3 there is another option: `ListCrudRepository`.

This blog post covers why `CrudRepository` chose `Iterable` instead of `List`.

https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/22/announcing-listcrudrepository-friends-for-spring-data-3-0

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this can help anyone in the future, but in your @Repository inteface, you could extend *ListCrudRepository* instead of *CrudRepository*

```
public interface StudentRepository extends ListCrudRepository<student, Integer> {
}
```

Then in your controller you can just get a List:

```
    @GetMapping("")
    List<student> findAll() {
        return studentRepository.findAll();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I know I am late to the party here but if you want to convert an Iterable to a Collection you can do it this way.

```
private <T> Collection<T> map(final Iterable<T> iterable) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false)
                            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
    }
```

After that, du can get a List by .stream().toList(); on the Collection. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can make your repository to extend JpaRepository not CrudRepository. This will work perfectly. Here findAll returns a List not an Iterable.