# GetPages error while migrating PDFBox to 2.x

Tags: java, list, pdfbox

Im migrating my PDFBox 1.8.x to 2.0.12 and have to fight some changes.

The last one that I can't figure out is occuring in the code seen below.

```
    public static byte[] mergeDocuments(byte[] document1, byte[] document2) {
    try (PDDocument pdDocument1 = load(document1); PDDocument pdDocument2 = load(document2)) {
        final List<PDPage> pages1 = getPages(pdDocument1);
        final List<PDPage> pages2 = getPages(pdDocument2);
        pages1.addAll(pages2);
        return createDocument(pages1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private static List getPages(PDDocument pdDocumentTarget) {
    return pdDocumentTarget.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
}
```

Error occurs on the last line, I have to change the old ".getAllPages()" to ".getPages", but then I get PDPageTree as return and not List.

Code is written some years ago and not by me. I have tried some things like casting or changing the types, but it allways results in errors in different places.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Additional to the answer, you can also try `document.getPage(i)` together with `document.getNumberOfPages()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PDPageTree` implements `Iterable<PDPage>`, so you effectively need a way to generate a `List` for an `Iterable`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6416706/1729265) illustrates many ways to do so, e.g. assuming Java 8:

```java
private static List<PDPage> getPages(PDDocument pdDocumentTarget) {
    List<PDPage> result = new ArrayList<>();
    pdDocumentTarget.getPages().forEach(result::add);
    return result;
}
```