# How do I retrieve particular List of element from MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I want to retrieve particular list of element from the Mongodb Table.

Lets suppose i have two variables in my Employee class-:

```
public Class Employee
{
private String Id;
private String Name;
.
.
```

now when i will make the fetch query it will be something like -:

```
List<Employee> list=mongoTemplate.findAll();
```

and then i will loop through each employee object to fetch the employee ID and save in the `List<String>`

Now, I want the solution in such a way that i can retrieve all the ID's in one go.Something like-:

```
List<String> employeeId = someCodeHere;
```

Please help if you can

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `Query query = new Query(); query.fields().include("Id"); List<String> employeeIds = mongoTemplate.find(query , String.class);`

Comment: Thanks @Veeram for your reply ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Mongos Reference documentation on distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) operation:

> Finds the distinct values for a specified field across a single collection or view and returns the results in an array.

In Spring Data MongoDB this can be achieved like this:

```
DistinctIterable<String> distinctIds =
    mongoTemplate.getCollection(mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(Employee.class))
    .distinct("id", String.class);

return Lists.newArrayList(distinctIds);

// or

BasicDBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
dbObject.append("name", new BasicDBObject("$regex", ".*and.*"));

DistinctIterable<String> distinctIds =
    mongoTemplate.getCollection(mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(Employee.class))
    .distinct("id", dbObject, String.class);

return Lists.newArrayList(distinctIds);
```

MongoTemplate offers here a couple of overloads for distinct. The primer query will collect all IDs for entries of a employee collection directly while the latter one will perform a filtering for only IDs of employees that contain an `and` within their name.

In order to convert the iterable result set to the requested List of String objects you can make use of [Guava's `newArray(...)` feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6416800/1377895).

As @Veeram also mentioned in his comment you can of course also make use of a projected query like

```
Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where(...));
query.fields().include("id");

return mongoTemplate.find(query, String.class);
```

where `query.fields().include("id")` is used to specify the fields you are actually interested in.

In contrast to `distinct`, this approach will contain duplicate entries in the result list, if there are any. While an ID should in general be unique, performing these two queries on names might produce a result that contains multiple identical entries however.

While the answer given by @Boris is technically valid as well, it might have some performance impact, unfortunately, especially if lots of embedded and referenced documents need to get retrieved as well. I therefore would not recommend such an approach.

Final note: throughout the examples I have kept the `Id` and `Name` fields in lower-case letters as this is basically [Java naming convention](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

Answer (score 3):

After a year, what you want can be done with the following code:

```
List<String> employeeIds= mongoTemplate.query(Employee.class).distinct("id").as(String.class).all();
```

Without the need of making any conversion. I had the same situation and resolved it doing that.

Comment: It does not work for ObjectId directly, works for strings like a charm.

Comment: Is there a way to sort this query (without sorting the list of strings after)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Java Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

```java
private List<String> getEmployeeIds() {
  return mongoTemplate.findAll().stream()
    .map(Employee::getId)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .collect(toList());
}
```

First you query for all employees, then convert to a stream, map `Employee` to `Id` and then aggregate all [non-null](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull(java.lang.Object)) values to a list.

If your `Repository` uses a Java Stream [query method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries):

```java
Stream<Employee> findAll();
```

then you don't need to call `stream()` method inside `getEmployeeIds()`.

**EDIT:** added filtering a null value from the Stream

Comment: Thanks Boris For your reply

Comment: can you please tell me how can i make sure that the null values are not added into our list?

Comment: @RishabhBansal You Can Use This To Remove Null Values From Lists ```list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));```

Comment: But When You Are Using Streams This is The Answer ```.filter(Objects::nonNull)```

Comment: @Boris Is this optimal? I mean is there a way to do this in a database query?

Comment: @Farhad perhaps it's not optimal, looking further in [supported keywords for query methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries), `findAllNotNull()` might be the one. Can you check if it works please?

Comment: @Boris Sure I'll Give it a Try Then I'll Let You Know